# Is there a metadata standard for native assets (talking about fungible tokens first) in Cardano?

Tags: native-assets

I've already made preliminary research about the standard.  The below link seem to describe it very well:
https://docs.cardano.org/en/latest/native-tokens/using-the-token-registry/token-registry.html
However, I'd like to ask whether or not is it safe to follow the instructions in the above link when creating my own native assets in Cardano Mainnet? Has anyone have tried to create tokens according to this standard procedure?

Answer (score 4):

As of now, there is no metadata standard/CIP defined for native tokens. But you can follow [this CIP PR](https://github.com/cardano-foundation/CIPs/pull/85) to know a bit of how the community is trying to define a standard for the same (your inputs are welcome).

Also, you can follow the metadata of some of the NFTs currently live to follow the schematics in case you are going to build a project.

- [cardanoKnitties](https://cardanoscan.io/transaction/172b10aad9179273a4161949759410c9ec5066426c87493e3cd56d5f9fcfe7db?tab=metadata)
- [cardanoBits](https://cardanoscan.io/transaction/f701d1e38ff07b570c636e17340ccdc82f46d2d81fce43b9e2fb7f4e4df09302?tab=metadata)

Comment: [A direct link to the markup file](https://github.com/cardano-foundation/CIPs/pull/85/commits/ed48e5a38b75eb31f16288338a3c1ef93fecde47?short_path=845f22e#diff-845f22e50f8ab4fbc50a67587aaf66ba2d18aa4c27c84d592ed08d22c8f570b7) is easier to follow than the git conversation. Also worth noting [the original Cardano forums discussion of the CIP](https://forum.cardano.org/t/cip-nft-metadata-standard/45687)

Comment: Thank you for providing information.  As I look on the links provided, the focus is really on NFTs.  I wish some other thread dicusses fungible token standards, as I can see a number of native assets floating around that aren't well defined (Ex.  token's icon/logo image not existing).  But it's good to see how standards for NFT are being discussed by a number of Cardano contributors at least.

Answer (score -1):

Cardano Improvement Proposal called **CIP25** defines [*NFT Metadata Standard*](https://cips.cardano.org/cips/cip25/).