# How can token metadata be stored onchain?

Tags: plutus, metadata

I was wondering how to link additional (meta)data to a token. Consider a trading card game which allows a user to purchase a booster pack containing cards via smart contract. Those cards should have a TokenName and are linked to the smart contract. But how would I link additional data like datetime of mint, card stats, edition, rarity, .. ?

Comment: Do these answers help you? [Is there a metadata standard for native assets (talking about fungible tokens first) in Cardano?](https://cardano.stackexchange.com/questions/351/is-there-a-metadata-standard-for-native-assets-talking-about-fungible-tokens-fi) and [Providing metadata to cardano-cli transaction build-raw](https://cardano.stackexchange.com/questions/359/providing-metadata-to-cardano-cli-transaction-build-raw)

Comment: Thank you, that clears things up quite a bit :)

Answer (score 2):

The metadata of a native token must be included in the minting transaction.

The token itself only has a Policy Id, an Asset Name and a Fingerprint.

Here's an example of a token, there you can see under the tab "mint transactions" the Tx and the metadata of the NFT: https://cardanoscan.io/token/59fdb627c01bd87326bef5f4df179bcccb2a2f43